Scipy.optimize.linprog does not find the optimal cost in this problem, by far. Why?
I have a random vector v and I want to solve the following linear optimisation problem :

This can be formulated as a linear program 
where W is such that [v,W] forms an invertible matrix.
To feed it into scipy.optimize.linprog, I write 
However, I do not find the results I expect. Indeed I am able quite easily to produce a feasable point beating the results of linprog (by far) by noting that the cost is at most k = np.linalg.norm(v)**2 / np.linalg.norm(v, ord=1), since z = k*np.sign(v) always verifies that z-v is perpendicular to v. Can anyone tell me why this is so ? Is there something wrong with the way I'm using linprog ?
Here is my code :
def random_orthonormal_basis(n):
    # Generate a random matrix
    random_matrix = np.random.normal(size=(n, n))

    # Perform QR decomposition to obtain an orthonormal basis
    q, _ = np.linalg.qr(random_matrix)

    return q

def affine_max_norm_min(dim_space, dim_subspace):
    U = random_orthonormal_basis(dim_space)
    v = U[:,0]
    W = U[:,1:dim_subspace+1]

    # find the point in v+span(W) that has the minimum maximum norm
    # ie. find min t s.t. -Wx-t <= v and Wx-t <= -v

    # Formulate the problem as a linear program
    from scipy.optimize import linprog
    c = np.zeros(dim_subspace + 1)
    c[0] = 1
    A_ub_withoutone = np.concatenate( (-W, W), axis=0)
    A_ub = np.concatenate( (-np.ones((2*dim_space, 1)), A_ub_withoutone), axis=1)
    b_ub = np.concatenate((v, -v), axis=0)

    res = linprog(c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub,  bounds=None)


    # hand calculation
    k = np.linalg.norm(v)**2 / np.linalg.norm(v, ord=1)
    hand_vec = k * np.sign(v)

    # I can even explicitely construct the feasable x tilde : 
    hand_x = np.linalg.lstsq(W, hand_vec-v, rcond=None)[0]
    hand_x_withone = np.concatenate((np.array([k+1e-8]), hand_x), axis=0)


    print ("We find that hand_x_withone is a feasable point : ", np.all(np.dot(A_ub, hand_x_withone) <= b_ub))
    print ("this point has cost ", np.dot(c, hand_x_withone))
    print ("this is bizarre, since we expected the cost to be no smaller than ", res.fun)

    return res.fun

 affine_max_norm_min(10,9)


I was able to locate the issue, and leave the question for future reference.
I do not know why, but linprog seems to think that, even though I gave bounds=None, I want a feasable vector x with only nonnegative coordinates. I solved the issue by correcting to bounds= (None, None).
